# In Makefiles, is it possible to create a generic rule with generic dependencies?

Tags: c, makefile

I want to do something like this:

```
$(BIN_NAME): $(ODIR)/$@.o | $(BDIR)
```

In this Makefile:

```
.PHONY: clean all
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

BIN_NAME=example1 example2

CC=gcc

IDIR=inc
LDIR=lib
ODIR=obj
BDIR=bin

CFLAGS=-Werror -Wall -pedantic
INCS=-I$(IDIR)
LIBS=

SRCS=$(wildcard *.c)
OBJS=$(patsubst %.c,$(ODIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))
BINS=$(patsubst %,$(BDIR)/%,$(BIN_NAME))

$(BDIR) $(ODIR):
    @mkdir -p $@

$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS) | $(ODIR)
    @$(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) $(INCS)

$(BIN_NAME): $(ODIR)/$@.o | $(BDIR)
    @gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

all: $(BIN_NAME)

clean:
    @rm -rf $(ODIR) $(BDIR)
```

But it appears that the $@ automatic variable can't be used like this.  Is there any way I can create a generic rule that I can use to create multiple binaries, using mostly the same source files, with the only exception being separate .c files (with the same name as the target binary)?

Comment: regarding the `clean` target,  Are you sure you want to completely remove all the files from the `lib` directorie?  That seems like a rather drastic step.   Suggest only eliminate the executable and the object files: @rm -f $(ODIR)/$(OBJS)  $(BDIR)/$(BIN_NAME)

Comment: this line: `$(BIN_NAME): $(ODIR)/$@.o | $(BDIR)` probably should be: `$(BDIR)/$(BIN_NAME): $(ODIR)/$@.o`

Comment: the macro `DEPS` is not defined in the posted code., which will result in the make operation failing

Comment: please clarify what you are asking, perhaps with a simple directory layout with file names.   For flexibility, suggest passing the executable name in via a `-D` parameter

Comment: @user3629249: the `clean` target doesn't remove the `lib` directory, it removes the `obj` and `bin` dirs, which get remade when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (and imo the best) way to do this would be [Static Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage)

```
BIN_NAME=example1 example2
$(BIN_NAME): %: $(ODIR)/%.o | $(BDIR)
    recipe...
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  I searched the docs quite thoroughly and missed this.

Answer (score 2):

Following is an example of a generic rule:

```
%: %.cpp
    g++ -o $@ $^ -std=c++17 -lpthread
```

If you invoke the above Makefile with say, `make testprog`, it will translate the above rule to:

```
testprog: testprog.cpp
    g++ -o testprog testprog.cpp -std=c++17 -lpthread
```

GNU make offers you many additional functions with which you can create fairly sophisticated generic rules. Note that `$@` represents the name of the target, while `$^` represents the list of dependencies. You may also use `$<` to refer to the first dependency in the list. `%` is the placeholder that indicates to make to generate rule by replacing the actual run-time values.